# Using CefBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync with BindObjectAsync Not Working

Tags: cefsharp

I am using the below code to try to bind a c# class that has been registered but do not see "dwgData" anywhere under Scope when debugging the webpage. What would dwgData be bound to?

```
    private void ChromiumBrowserForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost:3000");
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("dwgData", new DwgData(), true, null);

        browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += Browser_LoadingStateChanged;
    }

    private async void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
        if (e.IsLoading == false)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("CefSharp.BindObjectAsync(\"dwgData\");"));
        }
    }

    private void Browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
        if (browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            browser.ShowDevTools();
        }
    }

public class DwgData
{
    public void showMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HELLO FROM JS");
    }
}
```

Comment: The object is created in the global scope, so you should have window.dwgData

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was missing